# Use past and present tense in the same sentence

Tags: subordinate-clauses, tense-agreement

This topic was discussed before, and I do know that tenses should agree when they're in the same clause, but hear me out:

*"I realized that, in order to make a real difference, I need an MBA."*

My logic: My realization happened in the past, but the fact that I needed an MBA is still a present-day problem (I still don't have it). Would such a twist be considered correct, or should I just go with the classic simple past in the subordinate clause as well?

Thanks!

Comment: Both choices are normal and common, in a case like this where the content of the subordinate clause is still relevant. If you use the present, you are putting a little emphasis on the fact that it is still relevant.

Comment: @ColinFine This is exactly what I thought. I've been looking at this motivational letter for so long that nothing makes sense anymore. Thanks!

Comment: You have multiple clauses in your example sentence.

Answer (score -1):

If you were to say

> "I realized that, in order to make a real difference, I would need a
>   MBA"

that would either mean you already have one and you're telling a story. You should probably say

> "I realize that, in order to make a real difference, I need a MBA"

if you're talking to someone about why you want the MBA. It kind of depends on what you're trying to say, but either one will probably work.

Comment: The OP is asking about the gramaticality of having past and present in the same sentence. You've answered a different question